# MVC 4 Preserving User's Form Selections after page/view changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way to preserve a user's form selections after the page/view changes?

I have the form image below.  The form values are saved into a class that saves the form selections into session variables.  I was going to access those session variables after the user returns to the page after clicking the "Run Report" submit button.  After the user clicks the "Run Report" button, the user is taken to a report page and then has the option to click a link to return to the form.

I would like to preserve what the user previously selected on the form before running the report.  What are your thoughts on this?

http://sunsunku-001-site1.smarterasp.net/temp.jpg

Comment: Can't you save them into the database?  Session has smells.

Comment: database is a good idea.  What do you mean by smells? (:

Comment: It's a euphemism for bad idea.

Comment: Session does not inherently have smells. It can be misused, but for a specific user's "session", that is exactly what it is designed for. You can save this information in a DB, but be careful. 1) Make sure you have the right to save this information in a database; if it's personal you'd better be sure it is secure. 2) If you don't clean this data periodically, you'll easily bloat your DB.

Comment: I decided to use session. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using session variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use Browser side storage -Session Storage to store the user choice in current browser session.
You can store the filter selection on click of 'Run Report' button. Then again on coming back to this page, check if there are any Session Storage value presents, if yes restore the filters based on session values.

```
function StoreFiltersInBrowserSessionStore
{
sessionStorage.ReportingPeriod = 'Value1|value2|value3'; // store pipe seperate valeus for first filter.
sessionStorage.Schools = 'School1|School2' // similarly store second filter.
}

function RestoreFiltersFromSession
{
if(sessionStorage.ReportingPeriod){
   var values = sessionStorage.ReportingPeriod.split('|');
   foreach(var v1 in values){
      //select the checkboxes.
   }
}

if(sessionStorage.Schools){
   var values = sessionStorage.Schools.split('|');
   foreach(var v1 in values){
      //select the checkboxes.
   }
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide a example of this?  Is there an aspect of this that is different from using session variables?

Comment: One downside is the user can disable this for the browser.

Comment: I have shared the code sample which you can use for this. @Jasen, now a days most of the applications are using this approach for storing the local user preferrences.

Comment: I don't argue that it's useful and may be popular. But the OP needs to decide if the disabled feature will break the application. Whether or not many others use this technique shouldn't factor into that decision.

Comment: can implement some fallback apart from this.